# Accepting a HTTP Post request in Azure

Tags: .net, http, post, azure

If in Azure I wanted to write an application that accepted an XML file via HTTP Post, should I use WCF or just create a asp.net (web role) to accept the input?

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 0):

Purely a matter of opinion, but if receiving a file is the primary purpose, then this is more of a web service, and I would lean towards a service-oriented approach such as that offered by WCF.

A WCF REST service would probably be your best best, especially if you can use .NET 4.

*EDIT (adding link):*
Take a look at this tutorial series that covers some of the HTTP Services enhancements .NET 4 brings to WCF

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/06/introducing-wcf-webhttp-services-in-net-4.aspx

Comment: Okay thanks for that - I'll look into using WCF, but from what I've seen isn't it overly complicated to use?

Comment: WCF isn't that bad at all, its just very powerful.  Its very easy to get buried in books/lessons that try to show you EVERYTHING WCF is capable of.  Approach it just like ASP.NET and you'll be fine.  I've edited the post with a link to (what I think is) a great tutorial on WCF HTTP (REST) Services in .NET 4.  First few tutorials in that series should get ya up and running.